# How to get a value of an attribute inside a loop using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code from my HTML form.

```
<?php foreach ($charges as $c): ?>
    <br><input type="checkbox" id="charge<?php echo $c->id; ?>" cash="<?php echo $c->amount; ?>"> <?php echo $c->description; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

when I tick a textbox I want the value for that element pops up.

So far, only the value for the first occurrence pops up.

This is the jQuery code. I know I'm missing something, but i dont know

```
        function triggerChange1(){
            $("#ch1").trigger("change");
        }


        $("#charge1").change(function() {

            var v = $(this).attr('cash');

            alert(v);    
        });

        if($("#charge1").prop('checked')){
           triggerChange1(); 
        }
```

Comment: You say you know you're missing something; care to clue us in, because I have no idea what your question is?

Comment: Except your function triggerChange1, you should put `$(document).ready();` between your code.

Comment: Do you want to alert value of the checkbox that was checked?

Comment: @Jamiec there should be loop somewhere in the JS code.

Comment: @АлександрЛазарев yes. Like if I click the first one, 100 pops up. the second one, 200 pops up.

Comment: @vekah I'm aware of that, but that wont solve it

Comment: @Richie - there is no need for a loop anywhere - see the upvoted answer below

Comment: @Richie Please start a new question for the edited in part.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly you should use a `class` attribute to group elements together. You should also use `data-*` attributes to assign any custom meta data to an element as creating your own non-standard attributes will render the page invalid and lead to potential UI and JS issues:

```
<?php foreach ($charges as $c): ?>
    <br><input type="checkbox" class="charge" id="charge<?php echo $c->id; ?>" data-cash="<?php echo $c->amount; ?>"> <?php echo $c->description; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Then you can have a single click handler to get the value from the element which raised the event:

```
$('.charge').change(function() {
    var v = $(this).data('cash');
    alert(v); 
});

// raise the event on checked elements on load:
$('.charge:checked').change();
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** As rightfully stated in [Rory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28986669/1144057) you should prefix your custom attributes with `data-`

What you need is a `class`.

```
<?php foreach ($charges as $c): ?>
    <br><input type="checkbox" class="charge" id="charge<?php echo $c->id; ?>" data-cash="<?php echo $c->amount; ?>"> <?php echo $c->description; ?>
<?php } ?>

$(".charge").change(function() {
    var v = $(this).data('cash');

    alert(v);    
});
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/0cude9jr/

Answer (score -2):

```
function triggerChange1(){
        $("#ch1").trigger("change");
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#charge1").change(function() {

        var v = $(this).attr('cash');

        alert(v);    
    });

    if($("#charge1").prop('checked')){
       triggerChange1(); 
    } 
}
```

And you should use value attribute and not cash attribute.
And then you can call `var v = $(this).val();`